# Python compiled module documentation

Tags: python, c, cpython

I'm writing a library for Python in C compiled into a python module and I have managed to get it working just fine, however the IDE doesn't detect any documentation and what functions actually are contained in the module. How do I make that happen? The documentation doesn't mention that at all.
Here's how i create the PyModuleDef struct:

```
PyDoc_STRVAR(parseFASTAdoc,
"parseFASTA(rawData:str) -> list[dict]\n\n"
"Returns a list of dicts containing FASTA data.");

PyDoc_STRVAR(parseGTFdoc,
"parseGTF(rawData:str) -> list[dict]\n\n"
"Returns a list of dicts containing GTF line data.");

static PyMethodDef eccLibMethods[] = {
    {"parseFASTA",  parseFasta, METH_VARARGS,
      parseFASTAdoc},
     {"parseGTF",  parseGTF, METH_VARARGS,
     parseGTFdoc},
    {NULL}       /* Sentinel */
};

static struct PyModuleDef eccLibModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "eccLib",   /* name of module */
    NULL, /* module documentation, may be NULL */
    -1,
    eccLibMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_eccLib(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&eccLibModule);
}
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? Most code completion engines use Python stub files (`.pyi`) for completions. The doc strings you provide in the extension module are only available at runtime after your module has been imported.

Comment: Oooooh ok right I'm using VS Code so I supose I now need to generate those .pyi files  to get that effect? What's the point of documentation that's only available on runtime? Anwyays thanks for the help

Comment: For generating stub file, you can use [mypy's stubgen](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubgen.html) as a base. It supports C extension modules, at least to some capacity.

Comment: Runtime docstrings can be viewed using the [interactive help system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help), which is probably their main use. Documentation generators like Sphinx may also use them

Comment: Huh didn't think about help(). Curiously enough works for my library so I guess I did something right. Will checkout mypy though. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After help from [@Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11082165/brian) I managed to figure it out. Documentation in your C file is internal and won't be picked up by most IDEs. You need to create a .pyi file that functions similar to header files. They should be located in the library directory next to the .pyd file and .py file. There are utilities like mypy that can automaticly generate a .pyi file for you.